# highlight an instance where a volume reported is unchanged from the previous month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
Fields:         Name   Month   Amount
Instance1:      Alan   Jan2018  120
Instance2:      Alan   Feb2018  140
Instance3:      Alan   Mar2018  140
Instance4:      John   Jan2018  50
Instance5:      John   Feb2018  50
Instance6:      John   Mar2018  60
```

In these set of values, I would like to highlight Instance 3 and Instance 5 because the amount remains unchanged from previous month for a same individual. Can someone please help?

Comment: What Version of SQL Server are you using? (2008, 2012, etc.)

Comment: Is that really how you're storing month? Why?

Comment: No this is just a test data. I was looking for a solution to compare the amount with previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Highlighting* would most likely be done in a *client* tool like Reporting Services. From a `TSQL` point, you could add an additional column to your result to signify 'No change'.  If you're on at least SQL Server 2012, you can use `LAG`.

```
--Setup demo data
declare @t table (Fields varchar(30), Name varchar(30), [Month] varchar(10), Amount int)
insert into @t(Fields,name, [Month],Amount) values
('Instance1','Alan', 'Jan2018', 120),
('Instance2','Alan', 'Feb2018', 140),
('Instance3','Alan', 'Mar2018', 140),
('Instance4','John', 'Jan2018', 50),
('Instance5','John', 'Feb2018', 50),
('Instance6','John', 'Mar2018', 60)

--The actual query
--Using a Common Table Expression, create a SortOrder column
;
With _cte as
(
SELECT *
    ,SUBSTRING([month], 4, 4) + CASE 
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Jan'
            THEN '01'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Feb'
            THEN '02'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Mar'
            THEN '03'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Apr'
            THEN '04'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'May'
            THEN '05'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Jun'
            THEN '06'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Jul'
            THEN '07'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Aug'
            THEN '08'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Sep'
            THEN '09'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Oct'
            THEN '10'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Nov'
            THEN '11'
        WHEN substring([month], 1, 3) = 'Dec'
            THEN '12'
        END AS SortOrder
FROM @t)

SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LAG(amount) OVER (
                ORDER BY NAME
                    ,SortOrder
                ) = amount
            THEN '**'
        ELSE ' '
        END AS NoChangeFromPreviousMonth
FROM _cte
order by name,SortOrder
```

---

```
| Fields    | Name | Month   | Amount | SortOrder | NoChangeFromPreviousMonth |
|-----------|------|---------|--------|-----------|---------------------------|
| Instance1 | Alan | Jan2018 | 120    | 201801    |                           |
| Instance2 | Alan | Feb2018 | 140    | 201802    |                           |
| Instance3 | Alan | Mar2018 | 140    | 201803    | **                        |
| Instance4 | John | Jan2018 | 50     | 201801    |                           |
| Instance5 | John | Feb2018 | 50     | 201802    | **                        |
| Instance6 | John | Mar2018 | 60     | 201803    |                           |
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks mate! Really appreciate